# Is it possible to create an arrow that points from a player to an end goal?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am in the making of a game that uses numerical tile maps, EX: `[1, 0, 0, 1]` and using javascript i render those maps on a canvas. I cant figure out how to create an arrow that constantly turns to point towards and end goal, even though i tried using several methods including getting radians and degrees. Any suggestions would be helpful. Here is a link to said game: https://jsfiddle.net/juinorCPC/0azfu2wp/

Comment: So no matter where you are the arrow will always point to the goal ?

Comment: yes, because i cant seem to figure out how to make the arrow always follow you and still have the correct angle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the most simple way is
Step 1: create new canvas
And stack it over old canvas
You can search google how to stack div

[image]

This is the basic of what you asking for

Draw the sideway arrow by canvas and finish with setTimeout loop and if else or switch if you want short

Example:
You at middle of map

The coordinates are x: 15, y: 15

The goals is at top right(NE count from player) of the map

```
ctx.translate(document.documentElement.clientWidthh / 2, document.documentElement.clienHeight / 2);
    //This will make arrow canvas always at the middle of screen and you just have to rotate it to make arrow direction to goals
            If(xgoal > x && ygoal < y ){          
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
//ClearRect so it will delete old arrow
             ctx.rotate(-45 * Math.PI / 180);.   
            //Draw arrow at Coordinates x:5 y:5 to make it have a distance from the player
            // Angle at top right is -45° Take the player as the axis 
            
           
            }
```

You can make another if else or switch to make arrow rotate when goals in another direction then wrap all the loop in --> settimeout <-- to make it always check where the goals and rotate

Sorry for trash english and trash code

Internet have many js better than this but i only know pure js

Comment: To make arrow dsappear simply just make if the player come to goal then not draw arrow if(entergoal != Yes){draw arrow}